# C# write textfile with encoding iso-8859-1 is writing utf-8

Tags: c#, .net, encoding

I want to write a simple textfile with iso-8859-1 (Latin1) encoding.
That's basically my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string file = @"C:\Temp\test.txt";
        if (File.Exists(file)) { File.Delete(file); }
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file, false, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")))
        {
            sw.Write("test1 test2 test3");
            sw.Flush();
        }
    }
```

Notepad++ shows as Encoding "UTF-8":

[image]

I have no idea why this code writes a UTF-8 encoded file!?
Any suggestions?

Comment: Hint: what bytes do you expect to be in your file, and what bytes are in your file? (As seen with hexdump or a binary file editor.)

Comment: Write some text with an umlaut or accented character to see the difference

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your file contains entirely ASCII characters. Those have the same representations in ASCII, ISO-8859-1, UTF-8 and many other encodings.

There's nothing in the file to say what the encoding is - Notepad++ is just looking at the bytes that make up the file and guessing based on what encoding it *could* plausibly be.

Note that given that Notepad++ has to guess, it's entirely possible that you could have the same bytes representing valid (but different) text in both ISO-8859-1 *and* UTF-8. For example, consider a file containing bytes 48-61-6C-66-20-C2-BD. That could be "Half ½" when interpreted as UTF-8, or "Half Â½" when interpreted as ISO-8859-1. Both are valid strings... I *suspect* that Notepad++ would guess that you intended it to be UTF-8, and display "Half ½"... but that doesn't mean that's what you *actually* intended.